# jfeinstein10 sliding menu library prevent Menu from closing when clicking on content

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I’m using jfeinstein10 sliding menu library

The behavior of the menu, when I click on content layout, is to close.

I’m looking for a solution to prevent menu from closing when clicking on content layout.

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_orange"
        xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        sliding:viewBehind="@layout/xxx"
        sliding:behindWidth="270dip"
        sliding:fadeEnabled="true"
          sliding:fadeDegree="0.7"
        sliding:behindScrollScale="1.0"
        sliding:touchModeAbove="fullscreen"
        >
    </com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SlidingMenu menu=(SlidingMenu)findViewById(R.id.slidingmenulayout);
        menu.setContent(R.layout.yyy);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it isn’t an elegant way to do it but I changed in class CustomViewAbove of the library

Method `public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` :

```
if (isMenuOpen() && mViewBehind.menuTouchInQuickReturn(mContent, mCurItem, ev.getX() +mScrollX)) {
            mQuickReturn = true;
}
```

By :

```
if (isMenuOpen() && mViewBehind.menuTouchInQuickReturn(mContent, mCurItem, ev.getX() +mScrollX)){
            mQuickReturn = false;
}
```